# Are premature babies more likely to be irritable and impatient?

Tags: premature

My daughter was born before the 30th week of gestation.
Now she is 4 and is quite lively and impatient.
Is it possible that her low birthweight has an effect on her temper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any studies either way, but it seems unlikely. Most four year olds are lively and impatient. My twins were born 13 weeks premature and one is firey, the other is as mellow as can be.

Comment: +1 I don't see any connection between birth week and liveliness. My son is a whirlwind of action, and has been since he could walk. He was born on time.